# How to speed up this numpy.arange loop?

Tags: python, numpy

In a python program, the following function is called about 20,000 times from another function that is called about 1000 times from yet another function that executes 30 times. Thus the total number of times this particular function is called is about 600,000,000. In python it takes more than two hours (perhaps much longer; I aborted the program without waiting for it to finish), while essentially the same task coded in Java takes less than 5 minutes. If I change the 20,000 above to 400 (keeping everything else in the rest of the program untouched), the total time drops to about 4 minutes (this means this particular function is the culprit). What can I do to speed up the Python version, or is it just not possible? No lists are manipulated inside this function (there are lists elsewhere in the whole program, but in those places I tried to use numpy arrays as far as possible). I understand that replacing python lists with numpy arrays speeds things up, but there are cases in my program (not in this particular function) where I must build a list iteratively, using append; and those must-have lists are lists of objects (not floats or ints), so numpy would be of little help even if I converted those lists of objects to numpy arrays.

```
def compute_something(arr):      
      '''
            arr is received as a numpy array of ints and floats (I think python upcasts them to all floats,
             doesn’t it?).
             Inside this function, elements of arr are accessed using indexing (arr[0], arr[1], etc.), because
             each element of the array has its own unique use. It’s not that I need the array as a whole (as in
             arr**2 or sum(arr)). 
             The arr elements are used in several simple arithmetic operations involving nothing costlier than
             +, -, *, /, and numpy.log(). There is no other loop inside this function; there are a few if’s though.
             Inside this function, use is made of constants imported from other modules (I doubt the
             importing, as in AnotherModule.x is expensive). 
      '''
      for x in numpy.arange(float1, float2, float3):
              do stuff
      return a, b, c       # Return a tuple of three floats
```

Edit:
Thanks for all the comments. Here’s the inside of the function (I made the variable names short for convenience). The ndarray array arr has only 3 elements in it. Can you please suggest any improvement?

```
def compute_something(arr):     
    a = Mod.b * arr[1] * arr[2]  + Mod.c
    max = 0.0
    for c in np.arange(a, arr[1] * arr[2] * (Mod.d – Mod.e),  Mod.f):
              i = c / arr[2]
              m1 = Mod.A * np.log( (i / (arr[1] *Mod.d)) +  (Mod.d/Mod.e))
              m2 = -Mod.B * np.log(1.0 - (i/ (arr[1] *Mod.d)) - (Mod.d /  
                    Mod.e))      
              V = arr[0] * (Mod.E - Mod.r * i / arr[1] - Mod.r * Mod.d  -                      
                  m1 – m2)
              p = c * V /1000.0
              if p > max:
                   max = p
                   vmp = V

    pen =   Mod.COEFF1 * (Mod.COEFF2 - max) if max < Mod.CONST else 0.0
    wo = Mod.COEFF3 * arr[1] * arr[0] + Mod.COEFF4 * abs(Mod.R5 - vmp) + 
         Mod.COEFF6 * arr[2]
    w = wo + pen
    return vmp, max, w
```

Comment: You should really look if the `do stuff` can not be combined with the arange, instead of trying to improve the looping mechanism.

Comment: without seeing what `stuff` it would e hard to give you concrete advice. try to see if you can use vectorized methods, maybe add multithreading/multiprocessing

Comment: and where do `float1, float2, float3` come from?

Comment: `np.range`and `np.arange` are super fast in general. maybe the rest of the code needs optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python supports profiling of code. (module `cProfile`). Also there is option to use line_profiler to find most expensive part of code [tool here](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler). 
So you do not need to guessing which part of code is most expensive.

In this code which you presten the problem is in usage for loop which generates many conversion between types of objects. If you use numpy you can vectorize your calculation.

I try to rewrite your code to vectorize your operation. You do not provide information what is `Mod` object, but I have hope it will work.

```py
def compute_something(arr):     
    a = Mod.b * arr[1] * arr[2]  + Mod.c
    # start calculation on vectors instead of for lop
    c_arr = np.arange(a, arr[1] * arr[2] * (Mod.d – Mod.e),  Mod.f)
    i_arr = c_arr/arr[2]
    m1_arr = Mod.A * np.log( (i_arr / (arr[1] *Mod.d)) +  (Mod.d/Mod.e))
    m2_arr = -Mod.B * np.log(1.0 - (i_arr/ (arr[1] *Mod.d)) - (Mod.d /  
        Mod.e))      
    V_arr = arr[0] * (Mod.E - Mod.r * i_arr / arr[1] - Mod.r * Mod.d  -                      
        m1_arr – m2_arr)
    p = c_arr * V_arr / 1000.0
    max_val = p.max()  # change name to avoid conflict with builtin function
    max_ind = np.nonzero(p == max_val)[0][0]
    vmp = V_arr[max_ind]

    pen =   Mod.COEFF1 * (Mod.COEFF2 - max_val) if max_val < Mod.CONST else 0.0
    wo = Mod.COEFF3 * arr[1] * arr[0] + Mod.COEFF4 * abs(Mod.R5 - vmp) + 
         Mod.COEFF6 * arr[2]
    w = wo + pen
    return vmp, max_val, w
```

Comment: @ Bokota: Wonderful, This works. Thanks for pointing me to vectorizing inside the loop. As an aside, if the inside of the loop body contains sequence-dependent elements, where the next value depends on the previous value (that is, the previous value and the next value cannot be computed in parallel), then the problem would still remain, wouldn't it? Thanks again.

Comment: In such case I suggest to use Cython or `numba.jit`. But on begin think if it really depend, or only your implementation depend (like max calculation in your solution)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `range` as it is approximately 2 times faster:

```
def python():
    for i in range(100000):
        pass
def numpy():
    for i in np.arange(100000):
        pass
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit(python, number=1000))
print(timeit(numpy, number=1000))
```

Output:

```
5.59282787179696
10.027646953771665
```

Comment: Thanks, but range() does not work with floats. I need floats.

Comment: @auser Okay then.